# Random connection resets between browser and Linux server - MTU wrong or ICMP not getting through?

Tags: connection, icmp, mtu, reset

I've been seeing random ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors in my browser (Chrome, Firefox or Edge running on different machines, Windows 10 1709) when I try to edit web pages on a remote Linux server running Ubuntu 16.04 LAMP. It's very hard to pinpoint but it seems to happen mainly when submitting large forms on SSL connections and it's been driving me crazy because I've been losing work.

Nothing in the error logs, no problem with ping or tracert between machines, firewalls disabled at both ends. It has all the symptoms of a networking problem but I can't be sure because it's so intermittent.

I suspect it's MTU related but I was shouted down and told modern OSes and routers should cope with any packet size and the problem must be elsewhere when I raised this last year.

I fired up Wireshark today and I see repeated lines like this which I think are coincident with the problem:

694 47.224124   192.168.1.90    149.210.138.83  TCP 1514    [TCP Retransmission] 53732 → 443 [ACK] Seq=3867 Ack=33955 Win=64512 Len=1460

192.168.1.90 is the Windows machine (browser) and 149.210.138.83 is the Linux server. The packet size is 1514 which I know is larger than my router (BT homehub 3) can pass. The "Do not fragment" bit is set. I would expect to see ICMP packets negotiating fragmentation but I don't. Yet pings are OK and firewalls are off.

A wireshark pcap of successful and unsuccessful form submissions and a ping is here (you don't need a OneDrive account, just download it as guest).
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvycuEtEj-isleIZMh8w_SHuoqYcoQ

If anyone can help shed light on what's going on I would be very grateful.
[image: Snapshot from Wireshark at time of error]

Comment: Modern networking equipment certainly won't have a problem, but not everything on the Internet is modern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - I modified the MTU size in my clients (PC, laptop, phone) and this reliably fixed the problem. I also confirmed that the problem returns if the MTU is reset to the default 1500.

An updated "Smart Hub" has now arrived and the problem is no longer present when using that (even with MTU reset), so I'm pretty sure my diagnosis was correct and the original Home Hub 3 was faulty. I suspect it was due to ICMP packets being suppressed, since I know it doesn't respond to pings (unwisely IMHO). This issue must have caused a lot of misery, since that was a very popular hub.